# WPF + MVVM + Nhibernate : A simple example?

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, mvvm

I'ma rookie and MVVM NHibernate. No I'm doing a project with MVVM and NHibernate. I need an example to facilitate studying.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of examples around for using both, they should be easy to find with [your favorite search engine]. It is better to ask specific questions rather than asking for beginner tutorials (which there are, as i said, plenty to be found).

For starters:

Good MVVM Introduction
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

NHibernate Article by the makers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx

Another article on codeplex that might be useful (WPF + NHibernate)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfNhibernateToolkit.aspx

Another SO discussing about Nhibernate, MVVM, WPF, aso
[Using Unit of Work design pattern / NHibernate Sessions in an MVVM WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604762/using-unit-of-work-design-pattern-nhibernate-sessions-in-an-mvvm-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice article (with sample code) using WPF.

[Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)

It does not use MVVM however, but MVVM relies heavily on DataBinding and the approach followed in the article is quite similar (I could say, even better).