# NHibernate, Sessions, MVVM and Repositories

Tags: session, nhibernate, mvvm

I am beginning to wonder if ANYONE uses NHibernate with a WPF or Win Forms application, such is the dearth of examples or text books on the subject. I am struggling to find "best practices" for its use, and especially session and sessionfactory management, with an MVVM WPF application and repositories. 
To jump right in, it seems that the preference is to supply the repository with an ISession. But, where is this instantiated - in the ViewModel? - and if so, does this not created an uncomfortable dependency between the VM and NH (or is that just simply unavoidable, no matter how you dress it up?) Any implications for a multi-user application?

With the repository pattern - should I use one large repos. for all objects (and hence one session) or, as seems more manageable at first sight, should the repositories be split up in some logical business-related way? - but, if split up, how then to manage sessions? In my case, a form/window does not just deal with one entity (maybe it should...?) but with more than one. I don't want the ORM side to be dictated by the UI form design (maybe it should!?)

And then again, SessionFactory - where, and when to create it - once, at app startup?

Any good pointers or references for an NH app that is not web-based would be much appreciated.

Here is a reference to a similar question, but it was posed over four years ago: [Using Unit of Work design pattern / NHibernate Sessions in an MVVM WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604762/using-unit-of-work-design-pattern-nhibernate-sessions-in-an-mvvm-wpf)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been using NHibernate with MVVM for years, once you get it going it's great. The MSDN article [Building a Desktop To-Do Application with NHibernate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) covers the whole issue of session management rather well and is definitely worth a read.

One thing that will make life a lot easier is the use of a good dependency injection framework. I personally use Ninject and one of the things I particularly like is its support for object scoping. For example you can set your NHibernate session object (and thus the entity repositories) to scope to the pages in your application using InScope, so anything within the hierarchy of a given page that asks the injection framework for a session object will all get a pointer to the same instance.

Lots of other advantages to going down this route, for example it's very easy to use things like Castle Dynamic Proxy to inject property change notification to classes so that the entities you get back from your database queries support it automatically and thus can be bound to directly in the view or subscribed to by other class instances in your model or view model. Same goes for lists, which can be problematic because replacing a database entity list with an ObservableCollection<> can cause the database to think the entire list has changed which in turn causes performance problems when every single entity starts serializing itself back to disk regardless of whether or not it has actually changed.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply. There is a nice example of using Ninject [here](http://www.emidee.net/index.php/2010/08/23/ninject-use-one-database-session-per-view-model/). [This Codeplex example](http://nhibernatewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/82138) gives another approach (session created in VM base). I have seen the To-Do sample and also the Ninject sample. One unending frustration is that the same and very simple examples keep being repeated and referred to everywhere e.g. I have yet to see any guidance on where the Ninject kernel shoudl be instanced - a real-world problem!

Comment: No reason why Ninject can't work its magic on itself, I have the kernel bind itself with ToInstance and then inject itself into anything that requires it. (Actually in a real-world app I expose it via an interface and wrapper class, but the basic principle is the same).