# Domain driven design is confusing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

1) What are the `BLL-services`? What's the difference between them and `Service Layer` services? What goes to domain services and what goes to service layer?

2) Howcome I refactor BBL model to give it a behavior: `Post` entity holds a collection of feedbacks which already makes it possible to add another `Feedback` thru `feedbacks.Add(feedback)`. Obviosly there are no calculations in a plain blog application. Should I define a method to add a `Feedback` inside `Post` entity? Or should that behavior be mantained by a corresponing service?

3) Should I use `Unit-Of-Work` (and `UnitOfWork-Repositories`) pattern like it's described in [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-Design-Patterns-Millett/dp/0470292784](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470292784) or it would be enough to use `NHibernate ISession`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a unit-of-work pattern on top on the NHibernate session:

[Why would I use the Unit of Work pattern on top of an NHibernate session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980584/why-would-i-use-the-unit-of-work-pattern-on-top-of-an-nhibernate-session)

[Using Unit of Work design pattern / NHibernate Sessions in an MVVM WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604762/using-unit-of-work-design-pattern-nhibernate-sessions-in-an-mvvm-wpf)

Answer (score 3):

1) `Business Layer` and `Service Layer` are actually synonyms. The 'official' DDD term is an `Application Layer`.

The role of an `Application Layer` is to coordinate work between `Domain Services` and the `Domain Model`. This could mean for example that an Application function first loads an entity trough a `Repository` and then calls a method on the entity that will do the actual work.

2) Sometimes when your application is mostly data-driven, building a full featured `Domain Model` can seem like overkill. However, in my opinion, when you get used to a `Domain Model` it's  the only way you want to go.

In the `Post` and `Feedback` case, you want an `AddFeedback(Feedback)` method from the beginning because it leads to less coupling (you don't have to know if the `FeedBack` items are stored in a `List` or in a `Hashtable` for example) and it will offer you a nice extension point. What if you ever want to add a check that no more then 10 `Feedback` items are allowed. If you have an `AddFeedback` method, you can easily add the check in one single point.

3) The `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` pattern are a fundamental part of DDD. I'm no NHibernate expert but it's always a good idea to hide infrastructure specific details behind an interface. This will reduce coupling and improves testability.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you first read the DDD book or [its short version](http://www.infoq.com/news/2006/12/domain-driven-design) to get a basic comprehension of the building blocks of DDD. There's no such thing as a BLL-Service or a Service layer Service. In DDD you've got

- the Domain layer (the heart of your software where the domain objects reside)
- the Application layer (orchestrates your application)
- the Infrastructure layer (for persistence, message sending...)
- the Presentation layer.

There can be Services in all these layers. A Service is just there to provide behaviour to a number of other objects, it has no state. For instance, a Domain layer Service is where you'd put cohesive business behaviour that does not belong in any particular domain entity and/or is required by many other objects. The inputs and ouputs of the operations it provides would typically be domain objects.

Anyway, whenever an operation seems to fit perfectly into an entity from a domain perspective (such as adding feedback to a post, which translates into *Post.AddFeedback()* or *Post.Feedbacks.Add()*), I always go for that rather than adding a Service that would only scatter the behaviour in different places and gradually lead to an anemic domain model. There can be exceptions, like when adding feedback to a post requires making connections between many different objects, but that is obviously not the case here.